# Expo stalls at 'opening iOS Simulator' on command line

Tags: react-native, command-line-interface, expo

I am trying to run expo to launch a react native app however after running 'expo start' the command line freezes at 'opening iOS Simulator'.

`npm -v 6.8.0
 node -v 8.3.0
 xcode 10.1
 expo cli 2.10.1`

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

EDIT:

I have also checked that Cmd T (slow animations) is not active.

Comment: Try opening the simulator first and then starting it from the command line

Comment: Still having the same issue unfortunately :(

Comment: @Craig is this issue resolved?

Comment: It has been resolved. It seemed that there was an issue with the permissions on my node_modules folder which was causing the expo start command to hang